# Cyrillic monospaced font

Tags: fonts, warnings, typewriter, cyrillic

I need to use Cyrillic (russian) monospaced font.

I chose courier and added

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

and

```
{\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont 
 blabla
}
```

and that "blabla" is displayed like usual text and there is warning:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T2A/pcr/m/n' undefined using `T2A/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 245.
```

How to fix this?
At the end I would like to have cyrillic monospaced font with possibility to write bold or underlined words.

**Update**

here's minimal non-working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
usual text

русский текст

{\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont 
curier?

курьер?
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There's no cyrillic support for `pcr` family.

Comment: Leo Liu, could you recommend some other mono-spaced font?

Comment: @klm123: if nothing else, you need `\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}` if you want to print russian; your min.ex. has `T1`, which definitely won't work, despite the cyrillic input coding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no cyrillic support for `pcr` family in TeX distributions. If you want to use Courier fonts in LaTeX, you may use some commercial fonts via XeLaTeX. For example, to use Courier New on Windows, you can use:

```
% UTF-8 encoding
% Use xelatex / lualatex to compile this
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{Courier New}

\begin{document}

\texttt{русский язык}

\end{document}
```

[image: result]

---

If you just want to use a monospaced font in LaTeX, you can use default font families. Then pdfLaTeX is sufficient.

```
% UTF-8 encoding
% Use pdflatex / latex+dvips / latex+dvipdfmx to compile this
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

% lh font families are used
\texttt{русский язык}

\end{document}
```

It is also OK if you use `inputenc` with `cp1251` option and save this file in CP1251 encoding.

Comment: I know about verbatim:). I need to draw bold or underlined letters.

Comment: @klm123: I don't understand. You said you need monospaced font, and this is monospaced font. Use `\texttt` is also OK.

Comment: Can I make some of my text bold in verbatim space?

Comment: @klm123: So you need bold typewriter fonts? It seems `cmtt` family (and `cmvtt` and `lcmtt`) does not have this typeface, but slanted font and italic font are available. (I'll recheck.) Anyway, my first solution using XeLaTeX support bold, italic and bold italic typeface.

Comment: your texttt example gives me ! Package babel Error: You haven't loaded the option russian yet.

Comment: great. cmtt works for me! Thank you very much!

Comment: @klm123: I hope so. If this help, you may [upvote and accept](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer) this answer (*and all other answers in you previous questions*). I noticed you have never upvoted or accepted any answer.

Comment: I  have already accepted your answer. But I won't upvote it, since what is written in the answer doesn't work for me. Currently only one comment was usefull.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4540/discussion-between-leo-liu-and-klm123)

Comment: sorry, I have document to write :) Thanks for help, but I can't accept what doesn't work and have no time and reason to make this work.